# Improving list comprehension on twitter query

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm working with the twitter api and I have this python code setup:

```
call_twitter = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=hello")
tweets_json = json.loads(call_twitter.read())
```

The structure of the api json output is

```
/completed_in
/stuff
/stuff
/results
.../tweet1
....../from_user
....../tweet_text
....../etc
.../tweet2
.../moretweets
```

I'm trying smallest list comprehension to get to a tweets "from_user" and "text" property in the inner dictionary. the best i can do is,

```
call_twitter = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.jsonq=alhamdulillah")
tweets_json = json.loads(call_twitter.read())

    for tweet in tweets_json['results']:
        text = tweet['text']
        from_user = tweet['from_user']
```

I improved this to,

```
text_list = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets_json['results']]
from_user_list = [tweet['from_user'] for tweet in tweets_json['results']]
```

I'm not sure if the "from_user" and "text" will always correspond to each other (in order) when I save them in 2 different lists. Is there maybe a way to grab both the "text" and "from_user" in one iteration without using a for-loop?

I'm a python noob, but thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
text_list = [(tweet['text'], tweet['from_user']) for tweet in tweets_json['results']]
```

This will give you a list of tuples, each tuple being `(text, user)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tweets = [(t['text'], t['from_user']) for t in tweets_json['results']]
```

This will give you a list of tuples of the form `(tweet, user)`

Answer (score 1):

As far as readability is concerned in may be better to keep the **original** for loop.

```
tweets = [(tweet['text'], tweet['from_user']) for tweet in tweets_json['results']]
```

As suggested by Gordon Bailey is a good way to get the desired information in a tuple `(text, user)`.

As far as speed is concerned: the list comprehension may be better.

In general if you're building a composite value a list comprehension is acceptable. If you're using a loop for it's side effect (printing for instance) the explicit loop is better.